# Class instantiating objects of arbitrary classes. What pattern to use?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I hope Java experts will not vote down my question just because it may seem rather primitive to them. So, this is something I want to achive in semi-pseudo code:

```
class Big {

    ? magic_field;

    ? magic_method (int _idx){            
         if (_idx == 1){
             magic_field = new Object_1();
         }
         else if (_idx == 2){
             magic_field = new Object_2();
         }
         ...
         else if (_idx == N){
             magic_field = new Object_N();
         }
         return magic_field;
    }   
}
```

I've already tried to ask this question, but in the context of a real world class, real fields and procedures, but did not get an answer to my question. Practically all answers reused the idea of generics and started with something like

```
class Big <T extends Something>
```

But I want stress it heavily thousands of times - `Object_1`, `Object_2`, ..., `Object_N` may be drastically different classes that do not relate to each other - they are not subclasses of some parent class, they are not subclasses of each other. They are absolutely different and in fact are black boxes for each other. So, the idea of `T extends Something` does not work, because there is nothing to extend. Though, I've provided a semi-pseudo example, in an answer I wish to see a real class - and for simplicity let it be generalized on two arbitrary classes. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure on this one, but starting a post with calling us nerds may not be the best way to get comprehensive answers. I have provided a basic answer to get you started.

Comment: Sorry! I changed nerdes to experts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic field simple should be an `Object` if there is no relation between the types (everything is an `Object`!)

Something like this:

```
class Big {

    private Object magic_field;

    public Object magic_method (int _idx){            
         if (_idx == 1){
             magic_field = new Object_1();
         }
         else if (_idx == 2){
             magic_field = new Object_2();
         }
         ...
         else if (_idx == N){
             magic_field = new Object_N();
         }
         return magic_field;
    }   
}

class Object_1 {
//...
}

class Object_2 {
//...
}

class Object_N {
//...
}
```

Comment: Yup : every class you declare in Java is, by default, a subclass of the Object class. (Meaning : if you class Big doesn't extends any other class, then it implicitly extends Object)

Comment: You mean of type `Object` or what? For a newbie it is absolutely unclear. Could you a bit elaborate on that and drop several lines of code, to make sure that it works.

Comment: Do you mean that I could replace `?` with `Object` and I'm done?

Comment: Yes, I have extended the example

Comment: Thanks! It looks promissing. I will test it in a minute.

Comment: I think there should be casting somewhere? Something like `magic_field = (Object) new Object_1();`. Or not?

Comment: No, you don't need to cast "up". If you have a var of type `Object` and you know (e.g. by instance check) that it is actually a `Object_1`then you can downcast it. Recall that all classes extend `Object`

Comment: I checked it. It is working. Thank you, sir, for your help!

Comment: May I ask one extra question that relates to the main problem? I think cgon is right, saying that "Then you should store also the type that you have bidden to your magicField variable because you need reflection to extract data from it". So, can you, please, advise how to use this `magic_field` later in the code, in other methods where some internal methods of Object_1, Object_2 , ..., should be used? In other words how can we cast magic_field back to a specific type to invoke its methods?

Comment: In case anyone else reads this (and @Jacobian feel free to add what you did do): when using `magic_field` I would probably use `instanceof` to check the actual type. PS I don't think that you need to store extra meta info as `magic_field` already has it.

Comment: Yes, I solved it without storing any meta. But can you, please, explain another point, which cgon is talking about. "What you ask is first of all is not vary natural in the java context if you do not want to use generics." Is your solution with `Object` "natural" for Java and are there any other possible solutions more suitable for Java standard programming?

Comment: I think what @cgon was saying that the idea of using `Object` was not very Java like, in that it wasn't very Object-Oriented style of programming. I have answered the question you asked, but fundamentally the question I want to ask you is why do you have a variable that can my "any" type? How is magic_field used later? Is there any common interface that all the types that can be assigned to magic_field can implement? So I think that is what @cgon was alluding to, that your question is not expected for an OO language.

Comment: In a real world I can imagine for example such a situation, where I need, say, one and the same interface for talking to different databases - sql, nosql, redis-like etc (or simply totally different and not related to each other - like Object_1, Object_2 in my abstract example). And in this case my class needs to contain a property (field) for storing a connection, which may be reused in other methods - to select (rows, documents, key-value pairs etc), to delete (rows, documents, pairs) etc. And this is why I need such a magic field

Comment: "Is there any common interface that all the types that can be assigned to magic_field can implement? " - yes, indeed. Just as in a concrete example above (one interface for different databases)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92049/discussion-between-jonah-graham-and-jacobian).

Comment: I'm there in the chat room

Answer (score 1):

Java is a strong, statically typed programming language. What you ask is first of all is not vary natural in the java context if you do not want to use generics. Maybe you can port it to a dynamically typed language like Ruby, Racket, Python vs or you can extend a type system for the Java language.

So you can write it like that as Johan Graham suggested.

```
Object magicField;
magicField = new ClassA();
magicField = new ClassB();
```

Then you should store also the type that you have bidden to your magicField variable because you need reflection to extract data from it.

Comment: I do not say, that I do not want to use generics. I just want to have a solution. And Johan Graham solution now seems to be the only one that works. If there is some Java-style solution to this problem, I wish you could share that and drop several lines of code.

Comment: As for porting to other languages, I just do not want to do that just because there is a couple of fields throughout the code which may contain arbitrary data types.